# How can I cut text from textbox and copy to clipboard?

Tags: c#, clipboard

Let me begin by saying I am a beginner programmer and I know my last code statement is incorrect.  I am writing a notepad application and I can't quite figure out how to cut text.  I know that when you cut text all you are doing is copying the selected text to the clipboard, and then deleting the selected text. As I said I know the syntax is wrong I'm just trying to show what I'm attempting to do.

```
private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText(); // will paste whatever text is copied to clipboard
        }
        private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.SelectedText);//copies whatever text is selected in my textbox
        }
        private void clearClipboardToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();//clears clipboard
        }
        private void cutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.SelectedText);
            textBox1.SelectedText == "";//line I know is incorrect
        }
```

Comment: Use `textBox1.Text` and the rest should work.

Comment: @SabeehHasan, that would be wrong.  If you cut then you're only cutting the text that's selected, not everything in the control.  In fact, the code is correct as it is, in that it will produce the correct result.  It's actually the paste operation that's wrong, because it's overwriting the entire text of the control instead of just what's selected.  It's better to actually use the methods of the `TextBox` that already perform those operations though.  EDIT: Ah, I missed the `==` operator that Peter Duniho picked up.  Correct property, wrong operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to just delegate the operation to the `TextBox`:

> [Cut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.cut(v=vs.100).aspx)
>   [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.copy(v=vs.100).aspx)
>   [Paste](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.paste(v=vs.100).aspx)

That said, if you want to do it manually, the problem with your line of code is that you are using the `==` operator instead of the `=` operator. The code you wrote would work, using the correct operator. :)

Note that `textBox1.SelectedText = Clipboard.GetText();` would be a more typical "paste" implementation. There's nothing wrong with replacing the entire text box's text if that's really what you mean to do, but it could surprise some users.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBox` has its own `Cut`, `Copy` and `Paste` methods.  This is exactly why you should read the documentation first.  Not surprisingly, the documentation for the `TextBox` class lists those methods.

Answer (score 0):

In CompactFramework we do not have TextBox.SelectedText.Copy() method, but we can use public static class Clipboard:

```
TextBox1.SelectAll();
if (TextBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
{
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(TextBox1.SelectedText);
}
```